# How to display all has_many items in index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two models, a calculation name and a different table with a bunch of calculations that go along with it. I have successfully established a one to many relationship (one name has many states) so that when I display calculation variables in my name/show view it works perfectly:

**names/show view**

```
<p><%= @name.calc_name %></p>

<% @name.states.each do |state| %>
    <p><%= state.orbital_subset %></p>
<% end %>
```

I would, however like to display variables in my state value on the index page of names. Currently, I have a nice list of each name but creating an inner loop that loops through the states doesn't seem to work well.  This works great too:

**names/index view**

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= name.calc_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The best solution I found online is of this format which does not work:

```
<% @names.states.each do |state| %>
    <p><%= state.orbital_subset %></p>
<% end %>
```

Should I be nesting two do loops on the index page since I am looping both through all of the names and through all of the states?  Here are my models:

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :name
end
```

The error that I get when I view names index is:
NoMethodError in Names#index

Comment: Does not work in what way, do you get an error or not the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
    <% name.states.each do |state| %>
        <td><%= state.orbital_subset %></td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```